# How can show the following inequality exponential?

Tags: inequality

I was working on a problem and reduced it to showing the following inequality:
‎‎\begin{equation}
2(1-e^{-x})<x(1+e^{-x});~x>0
\end{equation}
your suggestion?

Comment: Your inequality is equivalent to
$$1 - \frac{2}{e^x + 1} = \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} < \frac{x}{2}.$$

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5Ex+-+1%29%2F%28e%5Ex+%2B1%29+%3C+x%2F2) shows that the inequality is valid for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The inequality can be rewritten as

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}<\frac{x}{2}=g(x)$$

To show it holds for all $x>0$, show that $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(0)=\frac{1}{2}=g'(0)$. Then, show that for all $x>0$, $f''(x)$ is strictly negative and $g''(x)=0$.